# Format(rs.Fields(1), "#,###.00000") to C#

Tags: c#, vba, c#-4.0, code-conversion

I'm converting some VBA code from Excel macro into C# and came across with this line of code.

VBA:

```vb
Format(12356, "#,###.00000")
```

How to translate this to C#?

Comment: Check [Overview: How to format numbers, dates, enums, and other types in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types). You can use `.ToString()`, `String.Format` or string interpolation with a format string. There are built-in standard formats or you can specify your own custom format. The thousand and decimal separators are locale-sensitive but you can specify the locale you want as a `CultureInfo` parameter

Comment: Are you really using such an old version of C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-8.0#system-int32-tostring(system-string)) with same format.

```
var numStr = 12356.ToString("#,###.00000");
Console.WriteLine(numStr);  //"12,356.00000"
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ecj272)